# Querying MongoDB with $near and $maxDistance together not returning any result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have in my MongoDB a Model defined like this

```
var Structure = {
    idMission: String,
    type: { type: String, enum: ['arena', 'gym', 'injury', 'shop', 'street', 'structure'], required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: String,
    address: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    messaggi: Array,
    ratipoingsList: Array,
    rating: Number,
    owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    coord:
    // type : { type: String, index: true },
    { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' },
    photos: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image' }],
    coverPhoto: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image' },
    validated: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    missionId: String,
    __t: String,
    location: {
        region: String,
        nation: String,
        city: String
    }
};

var StructureSchema = new mongoose.Schema(base, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    test: 'kind',
    timestamps: true
}).plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

As you can see, it follows the Mongoose standards.
When I try to define a query for recover all the nearest structures to a certain point, I won't get any results though the database does have results.
This is the query that I am using

```
  var LAT = parseFloat(req.body.lat);
  var LNG = parseFloat(req.body.lng);
  var accuracy = 50000; //50km
  var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [LAT, LNG] };

  query = { $and: [{ $or: [{ validated: true }] }, { 'coord': {$near: {$geometry: point,$maxDistance: accuracy}}}] };
```

which is based on a 2d sphere object as far as I understood. Using this query, I'm getting a response with no objects and that's not the behaviour I'm expecting since I have at least 2 nearest structures to the point I'm trying to query.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "count": 0,
    "structures": []
}
```

Here's what happens if I remove the $maxDistance parameter: Mongoose DO find values (Actually, all the values that I have on the DB)

```
{
    "success": true,
    "count": 4,
    "structures": [
        {
            "_id": "5bf52ea5ad36430730df85a1",
            "name": "Test",
            "type": "structure",
            "coord": [
                41.899402,
                12.640591
            ],
            "validated": true,
            "id": "5bf52ea5ad36430730df85a1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5bf526df2855722bf8d885ae",
            "name": "San",
            "type": "structure",
            "coord": [
                41.965234,
                12.546633
            ],
            "validated": true,
            "id": "5bf526df2855722bf8d885ae"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5bf3dbe095d01d2304a5c4b7",
            "name": "San lollo",
            "type": "structure",
            "coord": [
                41.966627,
                12.547382
            ],
            "validated": true,
            "id": "5bf3dbe095d01d2304a5c4b7"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5bf52d8fad36430730df85a0",
            "name": "Sanfrancesco",
            "type": "structure",
            "coord": [
                42.296604,
                12.182036
            ],
            "validated": true,
            "id": "5bf52d8fad36430730df85a0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where am I wrong in this query?

Comment: You're storing as a legacy pair and not GeoJSON. Distances are therefore in "radians" and not "meters" as you are expecting.

Comment: [Quoting docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) *"When specifying a **legacy coordinate**, you can use the optional $maxDistance specification to limit the $near results by **distance in radians**. $maxDistance limits the results to those documents that are at most the specified distance from the center point."*

Comment: See also [Calculate Distance Using Spherical Geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/)

Comment: @NeilLunn 50000 (my radius) / 6378.1 (earth radius) is still not returning nothing

Comment: So what is the actual Point being queried from? And are any of the documents shown in your question actually going to match that? Because that's what you are expected to provide. Bottom line is "MongoDB does actually work" ( shock ) so the only thing wrong is your code or your data.

Comment: @NeilLunn  These are the coordinates that I'm passing from input: 41.971695 as lat, 12.543639 as long. The structure with the name "San Lollo" should be the closest (600 meters distance)

Comment: When you say passing, how have you actually verified this? You should add some logging statements tot your code to make sure you are getting what you think. `mongoose.set('debug', true)` will actually log all queries and statements sent to MongoDB.

Comment: This is what MongoDB receives as a query Mongoose: structures.find({ '$and': [ { '$or': [ { validated: true } ] }, { coord: { '$near': { '$maxDistance': 7.839325190887568, '$geometry': { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 41.971695, 12.543639 ] } } } } ] }, { fields: { _id: 1, name: 1, coord: 1, description: 1, validated: 1, type: 1, __t: 1 } })

Comment: Okay so it is actually meters despite the storage. `.find({ coord: { '$near': { '$maxDistance': 50000, '$geometry': { 
'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [ 41.971695, 12.543639 ]  } } } })` works fine. And as a sanity test `.find({ coord: { '$geoWithin': { '$centerSphere': [[ 41.971695, 12.543639 ], 50 / 6378.1 ] } } })` returns the same, just as it should. Just not ordered like `$near` does.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you, it works! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it